# WiX - How do I prevent ComPlusAssembly being unregistered during uninstall?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3, uninstallation

As part of my Installer, I am adding files to an existing COM+ package.  I have defined a ComPlusApplication underneath my Product element, which has the name set to a property - I then have a custom action which looks up that property - all good so far.

When the installer adds the files, within the same component I have added a ComPlusAssembly which adds the assembly to the ComPlusApplication I defined above - this is also working correctly.

When uninstalled however, I am receiving an error related to being unable to find the COM+ application, this is because I am not running my custom action to look up the name of the COM+ package.  Basically I do not want to remove my files or unregister the component package as part of the uninstallation process - How do I achieve this?

I am using WiX 3.0 with VS2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Component/@Permanent="yes".

Comment: This doesn't prevent the com plus application itself from being removed on uninstall - I have reworked it to use a custom action to shutdown and clear down the component package as part of the uninstall allowing the files to be removed successfully.

As a workaround I have created a VBScript custom action to manually add the components to the package due to this and have removed the COMPlusApplication completely - I am unable to use the COMAdmin tools from a managed custom action due to including the interop (see another of my questions).